# How to load parts of bash alias only when logging in via ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, tmux, .bash-profile

As the title states, is it possible to have an alias only load when I access the machine through `ssh`, or better yet, only from a specific computer through `ssh`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `.bashrc` (or where you define the aliases), you can make it conditional based on the variable `SSH_CONNECTION`, which is set only for ssh connections. For example:

```
if [[ $SSH_CONNECTION == *"your-IP"* ]]; then
  alias ll="ls -l"
  # your other aliases
fi
```

Comment: Is there a way to check the MAC address rather than the IP? Or is that bad practice?

Comment: No, it is not possible unless you configure the clients somehow to send the MAC too. Identifying by mac is not a good idea.,

Answer (score 0):

As i interpret your question, when you ssh to a linux box with an user other than root, the logged in user should have only limited access to the commands and you also want aliases to that commands. The possible solution is

1. Create a restricted shell by copying bash file in /bin directory
   cp /bin/bash /bin/rbash
2. Modify the user bash to the restricted bash
   useradd -s /bin/rbash , in case of existing user usermod -s /bin/rbash . After this the user will be able to access only his home directory.
3. Create a directory under /home//commands
4. Now to restrict the access of the commands add the following lines to /home//.bash_profile file
         PATH=$HOME/commands
         export PATH
5. Create softlinks to the commands in /home//commands folder which you want to give permission to the user
         e.g: ln -s /bin/date /home//commands/
6. As logged in user can modify the /home//.bash_profile you have to make it immutable so that user cannot access it.
        chattr +i /home//.bash_profile

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to restrict the permissions of a user to use an alias. The purpose was to have tmux -CC get aliased as tmux when I login over ssh. Thanks for the answer, I didn't know that that was possible.